# set Cookie variable dynamically using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I have unique id's in my page and I want to create cookie for all that id's, I don't know how to deal with this, I have defined cookie using jquery, my code looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
      $.each(event_detail, function(index, element)
           {

                        if(index == "type")
                        {

                          var newactivity = element;
                          var task_id = event_detail.data.bug_id;
                          var project_id = event_detail.data.project_id;
                          $.cookie('task_id', task_id );
                        }
           }



        </script>
```

my code is working properly but it is storing only one value in cookie variable but I don't know how can I create a cookie for all the task id's and from this id's I need to set my webpage's values.

Comment: Well.. have you tried settings another one? Or using a loop? How is your list of ids stored? It isn't really possible to offer a solution based on what you have provided

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: You can only store one value per cookie. If you want to store multiple values you would need to serialise the data before putting it in the cookie.

Comment: actually i am getting notification form server sent events so if any of the task is having unread count then i need to store them in cookie and if user    is logged out then when it logins back it should have notification